# Generate 1000 random samples of 4 digits with replacement from the population of digits

Tags: r, random

Generate 1000 random samples of 4 digits with replacement from the population of digits (pop). Plot the distribution of the sample proportion of 1’s using a Histogram.

I've tried this, but don't believe that it is right:

```
set.seed(123)

pop <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

y<-replicate(1000,sample(pop, size=4, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)

d<-length(y)
```

Taking the observation 1 from vector x and storing it in variable b

```
e<-x[x==1]
```

The number of ones stored in vector x stored in vector c

```
f<-length(e)
```

Finding the proportion of 1s in vector x

```
prop<-f/d

prop
```

Additionally, I've tried to make a histogram out of this code, but it won't return anything for some reason. any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you would create a minimal working example. You don't specify `pop` and it's not clear to me at least what you're actually trying to do. I think if you supplied a short sample `pop` and a short `y`, (use 10 instead of 1000) and then explained exactly what output you're trying to compute, someone might be able to help.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald sorry for the confusion. I added what I meant by pop. I've also cleared up the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually correct:

```
set.seed(123)
pop <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
y<-replicate(1000,sample(pop, size=4, replace = TRUE), simplify = FALSE)
```

This is a list, because you specify, `simplify = FALSE`, check by doing:

```
class(y)
[1] "list"
```

You can see how it's structured:

```
y[1:3]
[[1]]
[1] 2 2 9 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 8 9 4 2
```

If you want to find the proportion etc, you unlist the list you have:

```
y = unlist(y)
```

For proportion of 1s, do:

```
mean(y==1)
[1] 0.09575
```

To get a histogram, do:

```
hist(y,col="steelblue",breaks=seq(-0.5,9.5,by=1))
```

[image]

You need to specify breaks in this case because the default is to include the left most, which will give you something really weird. Or in your situation something below is also good:

```
barplot(table(y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this is what you wish to accomplish, but I think it might be really close.

```
library("purrr")

#Your population, vector with integers
pop <- 1:40
#get a vector of 1000 repetitions of sampling pop by 4 elements with replacement
df <- unlist(1:1000 %>%
    map(function(x) sample(pop,4,replace = T)))
#Get the proportion of ones in the df
prop <- length(df[df == 1]) / length(df)

#For example
#  0.02375
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Any way you could help me make a histogram of the proportion? I've been trying to make a histogram of the proportion of the 1's for each of the samples and couldn't figure that out.

I reallly appreciate your help

Comment: You could do something like: `library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(nums = df)
ggplot(df, aes(x = nums)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,40,1))`